# How I limit cart creation to (specific url) "/api/cart/" URL only?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The following class was designed for creating cart and add items to it

```
class CartAPIView(TokenMixin, CartUpdateAPIMixin, APIView):

    cart = None

    # get the cart from token otherwise create new cart
    def get_cart(self):
        # if the token exist get it from the request
        token_data = self.request.GET.get('token')

        # create dummy cart object
        cart_obj = None

        # if the get request has token, decode it, get cart_id, return cart object
        if token_data:
            # token_dict = ast.literal_eval(base64.standard_b64decode(token_data.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8"))
            token_dict = self.parse_token(token=token_data)
            cart_id = token_dict.get("cart_id")
            print(cart_id)
            try:
                cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
            except:
                pass
            self.token = token_data


        # If no cart passed in the request it will create new cart object 
        if cart_obj == None:
            cart = Cart()
            cart.tax_percentage = 0.075
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                cart.user = self.request.user
            cart.save()
            data = {
                "cart_id": cart.id,
            }
            # use the create_token from the mixins to create the token for the new cart
            self.create_token(data)
            cart_obj = cart
        return cart_obj


    # The entry point for /cart/ API to create & update cart
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # First either i will get the cart data or i wil create new one 
        cart = self.get_cart()
        self.cart = cart
        # if the get call has cart and has item it will update the cart 
        self.update_cart()

        # getting the cart items through serializer 
        items = CartItemSerializer(cart.cartitem_set.all(), many=True)
        data = {
            "token": self.token,
            "cart" : cart.id,
            "count": cart.items.count(),
            "items": items.data,
            "total": cart.total,
            "subtotal": cart.subtotal,
            "tax_total": cart.tax_total,
            
        }
        return Response(data)
```

The URLs in use to maintain the cart are

create new cart

`/api/cart/`

get cart information

`/api/cart/?token=eydjYXJ0X2lkJzogMTh9`

add item along with quantity

`/api/cart/?token=eydjYXJ0X2lkJzogMTh9&item=3&qty=10`

delete item from cart

`/api/cart/?token=eydjYXJ0X2lkJzogMTh9&item=3&qty=10&delete=true`

the `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Django debug tool bar
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    
    # JWT Token => Login API 
    path('api/user/login/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),

    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),

    # Categories APIs
    path('api/categories/', CategoryListAPIView.as_view(), name="categories_list"),
    path('api/categories/<int:pk>/', CategoryRetrieveAPIView.as_view(), name="category_details"),

    # Products APIs
    path('api/products/', ProductListAPIView.as_view(), name="products_list"),
    path('api/products/<int:pk>/', ProductRetrieveAPIView.as_view(), name="product_details"),

    # API for guest checkout who has email only
    path('api/user/checkout/', UserCheckoutAPI.as_view(), name="user_checkout_api"),

    # Cart 
    path('api/cart/', CartAPIView.as_view(), name="cart_api"),

    # Checkout 
    path('api/checkout/', CheckoutAPIView.as_view(), name="checkout_api"),

]
```

## The problem is

If someone hit the cart with any URL parameters the get_cart function will create new cart by default
for example if any one hit the cart with the following URL
`/api/cart/?cart_id=blabla`

The get cart function will create new cart

## The question is

How I limit cart creation to `/api/cart/` URL only? with keeping other valid parameters works `token`, `qty`, and `delete`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide ```urls.py``` file

Comment: @AyushGupta here we are I have edited the question and added url.py

Comment: FYI Putting tokens into the query string introduces several security risks.

Comment: why don't you try to use Path converters. It is more secure than tokens. See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

Comment: @KlausD. what could be the alternative then? change the methods to POST?

Comment: Put the tokens in headers, the session, cookies, everywhere else is not secure than the URL.

Comment: @AyushGupta converters is good solution thanks

Comment: @KlausD. so instead of get i should implement it in POST?